# when is static member initialized in c++?

Tags: c++

when I run the following program,It prints "A's constructor called",But I don't define any object,So when is static member initialized and destroyed?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl;  }
};

class B
{
    static A a;
public:
    B() { cout << "B's constructor called " << endl; }
    static A getA() { return a; }
};
A B::a;
int main()
{
  // B b;
    //  A a = b.getA();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did with `A B::a;`

Answer (score 1):

This is the object definition:

```
A B::a;
```

It is constructed at some point before the first call to a function in this translation unit. Since this is the unit of `main()`, the constructor runs at some point before `main()` is entered.   If there were other global objects in this same unit, their constructors would run in the same order the objects are defined.